# In AlertDialog buttons being shown in the vertical orientation

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

targetSdkVersion 23

When I tried to add 3 buttons on my `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`, buttons being shown in the vertical orientation (and not in horinzontal). It is a bug ?

Here is my code :

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage("My message")
                .setPositiveButton("Positive Button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Negative Button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {

                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton("Neutral Button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {

                    }
                })
                .show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

it is because the names are long try short names like OK instead of positive button,cancel instead of negative and so on

Comment: but I have only two buttons with short names and still vertical

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try to customize your Alert dialog.

Just write a simple style:

```
<style name="RightButtonsDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/RightButtonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="RightButtonBarButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:gravity">end</item>
</style>
```

Hos to use style:  `AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.RightButtonBarButtonStyle)`